# Event Sourcing With an Event Store and an ORM

Tags: django, orm, apache-kafka, cqrs, event-sourcing

I am building an Authentication Service with Django for a micro-services architecture. its more of an experiment than a real world implementation to understand more about event sourcing.

I do understand that Django has an ORM which is very coupled with the framework and using Flask would be an easier approach but i am trying to figure out a way around it.

The use case is very simple. A user registers he would get an email to activate his account. a user gets activated again i shoot an email to inform him about his account being active.

From my understanding is that in an event sourced system. events are triggered and stored and we can get the latest state and store it in a database for example. in my case it would be Postgres using Django ORM.

I publish the event to kafka using the signals in django. pre_save() signals. and then the model will save the object.

In case of an update which is not yet implemented bellow. I would publish only the updated fields. and update the object in Django.

Does anyone see any caveats with this approach or would it be better to implement this in the save method of the model ?

I would love to hear your feedback on that.

```py
# app/services.py

class KafkaService:

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=settings.KAFKA_BROKERS,
                                          value_serializer=lambda m: json.dumps(m).encode('ascii'))
        except KafkaError as ke:
            logger.exception(f"Something went wrong creating a kafka producer: {ke}")
            self.producer = None
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.exception(f"Something went wrong creating a kafka producer: {ex}")
            self.producer = None

    def publish(self, topic, key, data):
        if not self.producer:
            logger.error(f"Kafka Producer could not establish a connection")
            pass
        try:
            self.producer.send(topic, key=bytes(key, encoding='utf-8'), value=data)
            self.producer.flush()
            logger.info("Message has been published to Kafka")
        except Exception as ex:
            logger.info(f"Errored while publishing to Kafka: {ex}")
```

```py
# app/events.py

class UserEvent:

    def __init__(self, event_store):  # event store here is Kafka
        """ A user event class which is an injectable. I am using here.
        I need a key for kafka to place the correct event in the correct partition.

        :parameters:
            - event_store: a class form example :class:`KafkaService` which publishes data
        """
        self.event_store = event_store

    def user_created(self, email, data):
        """ Publish an event to the event store when a user is created

        :param email: string
        :param data: string - json
        """
        self.event_store.publish('user-created', email, data)

    def user_activated(self, email, data):
        """ Publish an event to the event store when a user is activated """
        self.event_store.publish('user-activated', email, data)
```

```py
# app/signals.py

kafka_service = KafkaService()

user_event = UserEvent(kafka_service)

def user_added_event(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        from users.api.v1.serializers import UserSerializer  # Avoid (Apps Not Read)

        value = UserSerializer(instance).data
        user_event.user_created(instance.email, value)

    else:
        logger.info("User Updated")
```

Answer (score 5):

> Does anyone see any caveats with this approach or would it be better to implement this in the save method of the model ?

The usual design separates the domain model (aka business logic) from the persistence concerns.

If the sequence of events are your source of truth, two things follow: first, you want to be sure that you successfully *store* your events before they are *published*.  Second, you want to be sure that your write semantics are "first writer wins".

If you get that right, and everybody understands that the model in the database can be "behind" the events in the event store in time, then you are in good shape.

Eventually consistent systems make "read your own writes" expectations challenging.  So you may have some extra work there.